# Add role and edit page capabilities

Tags: pages, capabilities, user-roles

i've create a new user role and i want this user can edit page and use custom post type. For custom post type i've resolve but for the page not function.

On backend the user can only see the page but can't edit. Where wrong?

```
/* aggiungi ruolo */
```

add_role('brokers', 'Brokers', array(

```
'read' => true, // True allows that capability
'edit_pages' => true,
```

));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `edit_pages` capability only allows a user to edit his own unpublished pages. It does neither allow to edit others pages (this would require the `edit_others_pages` capability) nor does it allow to publish or edit published pages (capabilities: `publish_pages` and `edit_published_pages`).

I’d strongly recommend having a look on this wonderful table: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table
listing up all avaliable native WordPress capabilities against the roles they belong to.